# V be a vector space over F. prove V is infinite dimensional if and only if there exists a proper subspace W of V which is isomorphic to V

Tags: vector-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

V be a vector space over F. prove V is infinite dimensional if and only if there
exists a proper subspace W of V which is isomorphic to V

Comment: Hint: Find a bijection $\mathbb{N}\cong\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$, then apply it to a basis of $V$.

Comment: @Chrystomath You don't know there is a countable basis.

Comment: Please use the body of the Question to give both a detailed *problem statement* (the setup and the goal) and some *context* for your problem.  For example, do you think this was an exercise assigned to reinforce your understanding of recent class topics? Is the problem interesting to you in some way?

Comment: @RobertIsrael Every infinite set (basis) has a countable subset.

Comment: @Chrystomath can u elaborate a littile more please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B$ be a basis for $V$. If $V$ is infinite dimensional, i.e. $B$ is infinite, then there is a countably infinite subset $C\subseteq B$.

Define $f:C\to C$ by $f(c_n):=c_{n+1}$, extended to $f:B\to B$ by $f(b):=b$ for $b\notin C$, and extended linearly to $V$ by $ f(v)=f(\sum_i\alpha_ic_i+\beta_ib_i):=\sum_i\alpha_if(c_i)+\sum_i\beta_if(b_i)$. (All sums finite.)

Then $f(V)\subset V$ but $f(V)\cong V$. This follows from $f$ being linear and bijective.